# Python adding variable as value in a dict

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in Python and have a problem. I can't add the value of a variable to a dictionary.

f.e

```
name=input('Input the name: ')
dict['Name']=name
```

and here's the error:

```
TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment
```

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 17):

Don't name your dictionary `dict`. That's a built-in. Name it something else, and you example should work, provided the dict object is initialized.

```
my_dict = {}
name=input('Input the name: ')
my_dict['Name']=name
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to instantiate the dictionary before:

```
d = dict()
d['Name'] = name
```

Answer (score 3):

Given your snippet, i believe you named your dictionnary `dict`, which is a python built-in name. You should use another name for your variable (**always avoid using built-in names for variables**) like:

```
d = {}
d['Name'] = name
```

Answer (score 3):

You may either

```
d = {}
d["Name"] = "yourName"
```

or

```
d = {"Name": "yourName"}
```

both would work

Answer (score 2):

You probably wanted to do

```
dict(Name = name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code too:

```
d = dict(Name=input('Input the name: '))
```