# Setting up a Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to write a program that creates a dictionary containing course numbers and the room numbers of the rooms where the courses meet. Then when the user inputs the course number, it should display the room number. For example, course number is CS101 and has a room number of 3004. When I input the course number, CS101, it should display the room number 3004. How would I go about doing this?

This is what I have tried.

```
courses = {}
course_num = {'CS101' : ['Room Number: ' '3004', 'Instructor: ' 'Haynes', 'Meeting Time: ' '8:00 a.m.']}
#course_num = {'CS102' : ['Room Number: ' '4501', 'Instructor: ' 'Alvarado', 'Meeting Time: ' '9:00 a.m.']}
        #'CS103', 'Room Number: ' '6755', 'Instructor: ' 'Rich', 'Meeting Time: ' '10:00 a.m.'\
        #'NT110', 'Room Number: ' '1244', 'Instructor: ' 'Burke', 'Meeting Time: ' '11:00 a.m.'\
        #'CM241', 'Room Number: ' '1411', 'Instructor: ' 'Lee', 'Meeting Time: ' '1:00 p.m.'}

search_course = str(input('Enter course number: '))
for key, value in course_num.items():
    print(key, value)
```

How do I search for the course number to get the room number, instructor, and meeting time?

Comment: Ok. So what is your question?

Comment: How would I set this up.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you tried to create a list of tupples inside a dictionary which i believe should look something like this.. try it out

```
course_num = {'CS101' : [('Room Number: ','3004'), ('Instructor: ','Haynes'), ('Meeting Time: ','8:00 a.m.')]}
```

a dictionary inside a dictionary may also be the solution for you

```
course_num = {'CS101' : {'Room Number: ' : '3004' , 'Instructor: ' : 'Haynes', 'Meeting Time: ' : '8:00 a.m.'} }
```

what you did inside your list was probably combining the strings together to make one string and not dividing it by key and description.
reaching a room number should be done as follows:

```
course_num['CS101']['Room Number: ']
```

hope this helps

Comment: so if I were to add another list.                                                             course_num = {'CS102' : {'Room Number: ' : '4501' , 'Instructor: ' : 'Alvarado', 'Meeting Time: ' : '9:00 a.m.'} }                                             How would I be able to search for them. Like if I wanted to input the course number, CS102, and get back the room number, etc., what would be the command to do so

Comment: try:
course_num[COURSE_KEY] = COURSE_DATA_DICT
for example:
course_num['CS102'] =  {'Room Number: ' :  '4501', 'Instructor: ' : 'Alvarado', 'Meeting Time: ' :  '9:00 a.m.']
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6914880/python-adding-variable-as-value-in-a-dict
https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html